# How to display balloon on the MapView, once map is shown?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I use [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/donnfelker/android-mapviewballoons) library to show balloons.
So, once user clicks on my marker, balloon is shown.

The question I have: how to display the balloon for particular item without waiting for user click?

**Upd.** how to identify i?
Currently I have the following:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // here I have extras.getDouble("lat") and extras.getDouble("lng") - 
        // the location balloon should be shown for
        ...
        itemizedOverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, mapView);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getCount(); i++) {
           // here I add markers, one of them will have lat and lng equal to 
           // the values passed in extras

    public class MapOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
        ...
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
```

Also, with regards to the following code:

```
//  BalloonOverlayView is a raw type. References to generic type BalloonOverlayView<Item> should be parameterized
BalloonOverlayView bov = new BalloonOverlayView(context, 50);
// What is item there? should be getItem(i)?
bov.setData(item);
// The method setPosition(int) is undefined for the type BalloonOverlayView
BalloonOverlayView.setPosition(i);
```

Comment: You are better off asking the developer of that library, who may or may not see this StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. Actually, I've already sent him a message, but hope that somebody here already implemented the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plase refer [this tutorial.](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

In `@Override protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)` method you can inflate that ballon ovarlay for your particular index. suppose your specific point is 2 then you can do following in above method

```
if(i==2){
BalloonOverlayView bov = new BalloonOverlayView(context, 50);
          bov.setData(item);
          BalloonOverlayView.setPosition(i);
          BalloonOverlayView.setGeoPoint(geoPoint);

          MapView.LayoutParams params = new MapView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, geoPoint,MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
          params.mode=MapView.LayoutParams.MODE_MAP;
          mapView.addView(bov, params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @LA_ do you want to show ballons for all the pins on map or for just particular one without selecting it?

Comment: In `@Override
 protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)` method you can inflate that ballon ovarlay for your particular index. suppose your specific point is 2 then you can do following in above method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure how to identify `i` and pass it is value to `createItem(int i)`. Could you please help me with the code I've added to the example?

Comment: @LA_ its upto you which specific point you want to show ballon for. Suppose programatically you found out that in your MapActivity then you can pass that `int showBallonForItemNumber;` to your MapOverlay Constructor as `itemizedOverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable, mapView,showBallonForItemNumber);` make proper change in counsturtor and store it in MapOverlay class then if condition you can use as 'if(i==showBallonForItemNumber)'

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I'll update the question once tried. I'll accept the answer once done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are no setPosition and setGeoPoint methods.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
itemizedOverlay.onTap(point2, mapView);
```

you have to identify it through the Geopoint, here is the description

onTap

public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)

Handle a tap event. **A tap will only be handled if it lands on an item**, and have overridden onTap(int) to return true

The balloons library already overwrote it, so you just have to call the onTap method.